# Where's my error in this numerical integration with Python?

Tags: python

I try to integrate the cos(x) from 0 to  2pi but I don't find 0.

My code use this numerical integration:

```
def rectangles(f,a,b,n) :
    h=(b-a)/n/1.0
    print h
    z=0.0
    for i in range(n) :
        z=z+f(a+i*h)
    return h*z
```

The function is:

```
def f1(x):
    return cos(x)
```

I use mpmath biblio:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps=300; mp.pretty=True
```

The call is:

```
rectangles(f1,0.0,2.0*pi,100000)
```

It's ok from 0 to pi/2, ok from pi/2 to pi, etc. but if I want from 0 to 2pi I find: -4.81.

It's very strange because if I write 1.9999*pi or 2.00001*pi it's works !

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Are you sure the printed answer isn't in scientific notation and you're misreading it?

Comment: print rectangles(f1,0.0,2.0*pi,100000) don't works, are you integrate from 0.0 to 2.0*pi ?

Comment: (With correction from @DSM) `z = sum((f(a+i*h) for i in range(n)), 0.0)` (The parentheses weren't necessary before I added 0.0 as an afterthought.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but if I want from 0 to 2pi I find: -4.81.

No, you get

```
>>> rectangles(f1,0.0,2.0*pi,100000)
0.000062831853071795864[boring digits deleted]...
-4.81306306411824111[boring digits deleted]...1775099222873051479e-301
```

and -4.813e-301 = -4.813 * 10^(-301) is very, very, very close to zero.

[Aside: the `/1.0` in `h=(b-a)/n/1.0` doesn't help much-- if `b` and `a` and `n` are all integers, you've already lost precision by the division.]